# Mysql ClusterJ Plug-in

Tags: java, mysql, cluster-computing

Mysql cluster comes with jars for clusterj. I downloaded  Mysql Cluster 7.2.7. In shared/java folder,`clusterj-7.2.7.jar`,`clusterj-api-7.2.7.jar`,etc. exist. But when I add them to my project class path and write my first Java application that uses clusterj, some classes  like `SessionFactory`,`Session`,`ClusterJHelper` is not included in the available jars. In another words, in none of the my jars includes these classes and then I cannot import. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really need to download the latest MySQL Cluster 7.2. SessionFactory, Session, and ClusterJHelper included in

```
clusterj-7.2.10.jar
clusterj-api-7.2.10.jar
clusterjpa-7.2.10.jar
```